# Custom sort file name string array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, string, sorting

I'm retrieving a string array of files and I would like to custom sort them by a substring in the file name...using C# **.NET 3.5.  Below is what I am working with.

```
         <%  string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("...path..." + pageName + "\\reference\\");
           files = String.Join(",", files).Replace("...path...", "").Replace("\\reference\\", "").Replace(pageName, "").Split(new Char[] { ',' });
                foreach (String item in files)
                {
                  Response.Write("<a href=" + pageName + "/reference/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item) + " target='_blank'>" + item.Replace("_", "  ").Replace(".pdf", " ") + "</a>");
                }
       %>
```

I'm a C# noob, and I don't know where to go from here.  Basically, I'm looking for a substring in the file name to determine the order (e.g., "index","reference","list"; where any file including the string "index" would be listed first).  Perhaps there is a better way to do it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So "index" is first, "refernce" second and "list" last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to order the array by the filenames. In general, use the `Path` class if you're working with paths.

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(directory, pageName, "reference");
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(fullPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(fp => new{ FullPath = fp, FileName=Path.GetFileName(fp) })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.FileName.IndexOf("index", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.FileName.IndexOf("reference", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.FileName.IndexOf("list", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ThenBy(x=> x.FileName)
    .Select(x => x.FullPath);
foreach(string filePath in filePaths)
    ;// ...
```

If you don't want to compare case-insensitively (so that "index" and "Index" are considered the same) use `String.Contains` instead of `String.IndexOf` + `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: That looks helpful but unfortunately I am using .net 3.5 which does not include the method 'enumeratefiles'.  Sorry for not noting that in the original question. If it were up to me I would upgrade to 4 but it is not my call.

Comment: Then use `GetFiles` instead, the only difference is that this loads all into memory first whereas `EnumerateFiles` lazily processes the files. Note that i've edited my answer. Now i'm using correctly `ThenByDescending` instead of `OrderByDescending` (copy&paste bug).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way I use when I run into this problem.

Define the order of the substrings in a list.  Then for each item, check to see whats the first thing that contains that item. Then sort by the order of the substring in the list.

```
public class SubStringSorter : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var source = x.ToLowerInvariant();
        var target = y.ToLowerInvariant();

        var types = new List<string> { "base", "data", "model", "services", "interceptor", "controllers", "directives", "filters", "app", "tests", "unittests" };

        var sourceType = types.IndexOf(types.FirstOrDefault(source.Contains));
        var targetType = types.IndexOf(types.FirstOrDefault(target.Contains));

        return sourceType.CompareTo(targetType);
    }
}
```

To sort your files, do something like

```
var list = new List<string>{ "baseFile", "servicesFile", "this ModElstuff"  };

list.Sort(new SubStringSorter());
```

And the output

[image]

You could even go one step further and give the substring sorter the list as part of its constructor so you can re-use the substring sort order with other items.  The example I posted tests if the string exists in any context, but if you are more interested in it starting with a string you can do that too.